# How to redesign code to reslove SonarQube "Getters and setters should access the expected fields" bug?

Tags: c#, sonarqube

Sample code:

```
public class Foo: Bar
{
    protected static readonly string Property1Name = "Property1";
    protected static readonly string Property2Name = "Property2";

    public string Property1
    {
        get => (string)Properties[Property1Name];
        set => Properties[Property1Name] = value;
    }

    public int Property2
    {
        get => (int)Properties[Property2Name];
        set => Properties[Property2Name] = value;
    }
}
```

`Properties` collection defined in base class and used in `PropertyGrid`. Real code much more complex - there are other classes derived from `Bar` and use `Properties` (hundreds properties).

SonarQube found bugs in getters and setter of `Property1` and `Property2`:

> Getters and setters should access the expected fields

I could suppress or disable SonarQube's rule, but the code above is error-prone - if a developer copy/paste code it could be end up with something like:

```
    public double Property3
    {
        get => (double)Properties[Property3Name];
        set => Properties[Property2Name] = value;
    }
```

Hunting for the above bug is not an easy task.

Any ideas how to redesign code to fix SonarQube's warnings and make the code less error-prone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid the magic strings and use `nameof` instead

```
public int Property2 {
    get => (int)Properties[nameof(Property2)];
    set => Properties[nameof(Property2)] = value;
}
```

Comment: Removing the readonly fields would resolve SonarQube's message as well.